# Read Parquet stored in S3 with pyarrow on AWS Lambda got a timout error

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pyarrow

I have a Lambda Function that is triggered when files are uploaded on S3 bucket. The files are in parquet format. I use `S3FileSystem` to read parquet from the bucket.

```
from pyarrow import fs
from pyarrow import parquet as pq
from pyarrow import Table, BufferOutputStream

s3 = fs.S3FileSystem()
dataset_path = f"test/test.parquet"
tb = pq.read_table(dataset_path, filesystem=s3, use_threads=True)
df = tb.to_pandas()
```

When I run the function locally(using credential file) everything works fine but when I run the lambda function I get a timeout error:

`Error When getting information for key 'test.parquet' in bucket 'test': AWS Error [code 99]: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached`

I am using pyarrow 6.0 for the moment it is mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Lambda function is in a VPC, by default it does not have internet connection. Any AWS API that you are calling is going through the internet connection.

That means that you have 2 solutions:

1. Create a NAT Gateway for the subnet in which Lambda function is located. NAT Gateway will enable internet connectivity and thus connection to S3 and other services. You can see detailed instructions for adding NAT gateway in [internet-access-lambda-function](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function)
2. Create VPC endpoint for S3 which will keep the connection private, completely within AWS. You can see details about adding Gateway endpoint for S3 in [vpc-endpoints-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#create-gateway-endpoint-s3)